# using selenium grid remote webdriver java client to take screenshots with messy characters returned

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I established a selenium grid 2 on one linux platform, with both hub and node on the same machine. Then I used selenium remote webdriver(java client) to take a screenshot of www.google.com.hk page. The result turned out to be messy:
[image]

All the rectangle characters are Chinese characters.

The system environment variable of LANG is en_US.UTF-8, and I started hub and node with '-Dfile.encoding="Unicode"'. Besides, my Java code was written in UTF-8 encoding.

So is there any way I can turn these messy rectangle characters into original correct ones?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use your browser profile and set language preference here. Pass your profile as a parameter while creating instance of your browser. check the code below:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("Your-profile-name");
profile.setPreference( "intl.accept_languages", "no,en-us,en" ); 
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.get("http://www.mysite.com/");
```

Note: I consider that you already know the concept of profile in browser.

Comment: Thanks, but it still cannot solve my problem. I tried to copy the firefox profile from my Macbook Desktop to the remote Linux platform, it still cannot take screenshot with Chinese characters. All I got were these same rectangle symbols. Besides, it's very ridiculous that when I coded some logic to 'fileElement' or 'getTitle' and then printed them out, the result texts were just right characters, no more rectangle symbols. Seems like the problem only comes out when it comes to the 'takeScreenshot'.